# md-checkbox nested inside md-radio-group

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

I am trying to nest a checkbox inside a radio button group using angular material. I have the checkboxes displaying; however, I am unable to click on the checkboxes. See this [code pen](http://codepen.io/jberke/pen/WGaZWE?editors=1011)

**MarkUp**

```
<md-radio-group ng-model="vm.TargetType">
    <md-radio-button class="" ng-repeat="targetGroup in vm.Targets" ng-value="targetGroup.Id">{{targetGroup.Name}}<br />
      <div ng-if="targetGroup.Id == 1">
        <div ng-repeat="p in vm.Phases">

          <md-checkbox ng-checked="vm.exists(p,vm.SelectedPhases)" ng-click="vm.toggle(p,vm.SelectedPhases)">{{p.Name}}</md-checkbox>
        </div>
      </div>
    </md-radio-button>
  </md-radio-group>
```

**JS**

```
(function() {
  'use strict';

  angular.module("myApp", ['ngMaterial']).controller("myController", 

  function ($scope) {
    var vm=this;
    vm.SelectedPhases=[];
    console.log('in my controller')
    vm.Targets = [{
      Id: 1,
      Name: 'Can\'t select child elements'
    }, {
      Id: 2,
      Name: 'Another Group'
    }];

    vm.Phases = [{
      Id: 1,
      Name: 'Something A'
    }, {
      Id: 2,
      Name: 'Something B'
    }];
    
     vm.toggle = function (item, list) {
            var idx = list.indexOf(item);
            if(idx > -1)
            {
                list.splice(idx, 1);
            }
            else
            {
                list.push(item);
            }
        };

        vm.exists = function (item, list) {
            return list.indexOf(item) > -1;
        };
  });
})();
```

**EDIT**
Looks like the content inside the radio button is contained within an element with a class of md-label. I'm guessing it's preventing propagation of the click event?

Answer (score 1):

Does this help? - [CodePen](http://codepen.io/camden-kid/pen/Zpqxpq?editors=1000)

I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve. :-)

Markup

```
<div layout="row" layout-align="start center"  ng-repeat="targetGroup in vm.Targets">
    <md-radio-group ng-model="vm.TargetType">
      <md-radio-button class="" ng-value="targetGroup.Id">{{targetGroup.Name}}<br />
      </md-radio-button>
    </md-radio-group>
    <div ng-if="targetGroup.Id === 1">
      <div ng-repeat="p in vm.Phases">
        <md-checkbox ng-checked="vm.exists(p,vm.SelectedPhases)" ng-click="vm.toggle(p,vm.SelectedPhases)">{{p.Name}}</md-checkbox>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Not quite, I want the checkboxes to be under the radio button. So the user has two distinct options (TargetGroup), if they select targetgroup 1, then they have additional options they can select.

Comment: Just updated my codepen showing how I will disable the checkboxes if the the first radio is not selected.

Answer (score 0):

Since you can't nest them you have to arrange the elements differently. See this [code pen](http://codepen.io/jberke/pen/BLGKyZ) for a solution.

```
<div class='row'>
  <md-radio-group ng-model="vm.TargetType">
    <div ng-repeat="targetGroup in vm.Targets">

      <md-radio-button class="" ng-value="targetGroup.Id">
        {{targetGroup.Name}}<br />
      </md-radio-button>

      <div class="row" style="margin-left:50px;" ng-repeat="phase in vm.Phases" ng-if="targetGroup.Id == 1">
        <md-checkbox ng-disabled="vm.TargetType!=1" checked="vm.exists(p,vm.SelectedPhases)" ng-click="vm.toggle(p,vm.SelectedPhases)">{{phase.Name}}</md-checkbox>

      </div>
  </md-radio-group>

  </div>
```